# Referencing Grammar in Xtext Validator

Tags: xtext

In an Xtext validator, I would like to assert that an Aggregate does not references another Aggregate

With this simplified grammar

```
grammar com.mimacom.mdd.ddd.MdDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

generate mdDsl "http://www.mimacom.com/mdd/ddd/MdDsl"  

Domainmodel:
    elements+=Element*;

Element:
    Aggregate | ValueObject;

Aggregate:
    'aggregate' name=ValidID ('extends' superType=JvmTypeReference)? '{'
        properties+=Property*
    '}';

ValueObject:
    'valueObject' name=ValidID ('extends' superType=JvmTypeReference)? '{'
        properties+=Property*
    '}';

Property:
    name=ValidID ':' type=JvmTypeReference;
```

When I parse the following, I expect to be able to find out if a property is a valueObject or an aggregate

```
aggregate Address{
}
aggregate Person{
    p : Address
}
```

The validation looks like the following
I was not able to extract the information from the property to find out
if the type of the property is an aggregate

```
@Inject
IJvmModelAssociations assoc;

@Check
def aggregateDoesNotReferenceOtherAggregates(Aggregate aggregate) {
    var features = aggregate.features

    for(Feature f : features){
        println(f)
        var s = assoc.getSourceElements(f.type.type)
        var first = s.get(0)
        if(first instanceof Aggregate   ){
            warning('An aggregate is not allowed to reference another aggregate'
                , null
                , aggregate.eContainingFeature)
        }
    }
}
```

I add the Inferrer here:

```
class MdDslJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {

@Inject extension JvmTypesBuilder
@Inject extension IQualifiedNameProvider

def dispatch void infer(Aggregate aggregate, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPrelinkingPhase) {
    acceptor.accept(aggregate.toClass(aggregate.fullyQualifiedName)) [
        processAggregate(aggregate, it)
    ]
}

def dispatch void infer(ValueObject element, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPrelinkingPhase) {
    acceptor.accept(element.toClass(element.fullyQualifiedName)) [
        processValueObject(element, it)
    ]
}

protected def void processAggregate(Aggregate aggregate, JvmGenericType it) {
    documentation = aggregate.documentation
    if (aggregate.superType !== null)
            superTypes += aggregate.superType.cloneWithProxies

    for (feature : aggregate.features) {
        switch feature {
            Property: {
                members += feature.toField(feature.name, feature.type)
                members += feature.toGetter(feature.name, feature.type)
                members += feature.toSetter(feature.name, feature.type)
            }
            Operation: {
                processOperation(it, feature)
            }
        }
    }
}

protected def void processValueObject(ValueObject element, JvmGenericType it) {
    documentation = element.documentation
    if (element.superType !== null)
            superTypes += element.superType.cloneWithProxies
    for (feature : element.features) {
        switch feature {
            Property: {
                members += feature.toField(feature.name, feature.type)
                members += feature.toGetter(feature.name, feature.type)
            }
            Operation: {
                processOperation(it, feature)
            }
        }
    }
}

protected def boolean processOperation(JvmGenericType it, Operation feature) {
    members += feature.toMethod(feature.name, feature.type) [
        documentation = feature.documentation
        for (p : feature.params) {
            parameters += p.toParameter(p.name, p.parameterType)
        }
        body = feature.body
    ]
}
}
```

the test I execute which gives me an empty source looks like that

```
@ExtendWith(InjectionExtension)
@InjectWith(MdDslInjectorProvider)
class MdDslParsingTest {
    @Inject 
    extension CompilationTestHelper

    @Test
    def void aggregateDoesNotReferenceOtherAggregate() {
        val result = parseHelper.parse('''
            aggregate Address{
            }
            aggregate Person{
                a : Address
            }
        ''')

    validationHelper.assertWarning(result,result.eClass,"failed to find the problem")
    }
}
```

Comment: am not sure if this makes sense. you seem to use xbase. but you may follow the reference and use IJvmModelAssociations to find out what the jvmType is inferred from

Comment: var simpleName= f.type.type.simpleName, This will give me the java type, But I won't know if it is an aggregate or a value type. I can get the same information via IJvmModelAssociations, but again, I only get the target Java objects. I know it is an address, but not that it is an aggregate

Comment: i mean  f.type.type

Comment: org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.IJvmModelAssociations.getPrimarySourceElement(EObject)

Comment: Unfortunately, org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.IJvmModelAssociations.getSourceElements() returns an empty list. thus getPrimarySourceElement() is null :(

Comment: How does the inferrer look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cannot reproduce this

```
class MyDslValidator extends AbstractMyDslValidator {

    @Inject
    private IJvmModelAssociations assoc

    @Check
    def checkAggregateReference(Aggregate aggregate) {
        var properties = aggregate.properties

        for (f : properties) {
            System.err.println(f)
            System.err.println(assoc.getSourceElements(f.type.type))
        }
    }

}
```

gives me the

```
org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.impl.PropertyImpl@15c4ae78 (name: p)
[org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.impl.AggregateImpl@6952cae7 (name: Address)
```

as expected

Comment: I recreated from scratch a new Xtext project. The source is still empty : \norg.fb.simple.impl.PropertyImpl@43af351a (name: a) and
[]. Is my test set up wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a complete sample and test

Comment: I just added the test

Comment: I just downloaded these examples (https://github.com/xtext/seven-languages-xtext) from github. When I run the CompilationTest from the scripting example  l still get an empty source. May be it has to do with the Eclipse version I use? Has something changed?
Here is my Eclipse version
Eclipse DSL Tools
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800

Comment: what is the model you test with?

Comment: and how did you change the validator

Comment: I was indeed unit testing it. I changed the class path. I added a jar. And know suddenly I got something in the source. I have no idea what changed, beside this. I will accept your response as a valid one, as it gives me access to the source. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Don't understand. Where do you infer address.

Comment: In your test I mean

Comment: My bad I was so focused on the dependency problem, I gave a wrong test. I edited the test and the validator. The test is still red but for other reasons. I will find that one late.